# Rasterize : actual size, within a code

Tags: image-processing, image, rasterize

How to get rasterized image of `actual size` ?

```
Rasterize[StringJoin[ConstantArray["a",200]],ImageFormattingWidth->1000]
```

[image]

As you see in the above video,
it can be done by creating a rasterized image, and then right click - popup menu - Actual Size.

But I want to do it within a code.

Comment: What is it that you want to do in code? When you select Actual Size, all you are doing is adjusting the display of the image. You aren't doing anything to the image data at all. If you want to programmatically control this kind of display functionality, you'll probably need to do your own `CellPrint`. But the way you ask the question makes me think you just want the image data to be the right size. That's a non-issue. If you were to copy-paste each image (the one before and the one after you chose Actual Size) into another program, say a drawing program or something, they'd be identical.

Comment: Thank you, what I need now is `CellPrint`. How to achieve it? (a single code that directly display the image in actual size)

Comment: Check Mathematica documentation for `CellPrint`.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted your question. Based on the gist of the answer you accepted, I now think AlexyPopkov and Coolwater and Kuba were on the right track. I suggest you follow their excellent suggestions (some on your other post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify `ImageSize`:

```
Rasterize[StringJoin[ConstantArray["a", 200]], ImageFormattingWidth -> 1000, 
 ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: screenshot]